# change order and size of elements in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change order as well as size of elements in bootstrap. here is my use-case.[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, add a question.

Comment: My question is on small screen I want to change size of element like col-xs-12 from col-md-4 as well as order of elements ? like see colors of above image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pull` and `push` classes..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-4">a</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-6 col-xs-8">c</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-4 col-xs-12">b</div>
</div>
```

Demo at http://www.bootply.com/iI3FpeZZrE